# How can I correctly preview a blob audio from a database without the player being greyed out?

Tags: php

I'm creating a page that retrieves blob audio files from a database and displays them using a CSS Record Player for previewing. Each time I try the player still stays greyed out.

This is my PHP code

```
try {
        
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        // Retrieve the audio files from the database
        $query = "SELECT id, audio_blob FROM audio_table";
        $statement = $pdo->query($query);
        $audios = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Loop through the retrieved audio files
        foreach ($audios as $audio) {
            $audioId = $audio['id'];
            $audioBlob = $audio['audio_blob'];

            // Generate a unique ID for the audio element
            $audioElementId = "audio_" . $audioId;

            // Display the record player and audio element
            echo '<div class="record-player">';
            echo '<audio id="' . $audioElementId . '" controls>';
            echo '<source src="data:audio/mp3;base64,' . base64_encode($audioBlob) . '" type="audio/mp3">';
            echo '</audio>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

This is my Script

```
 <script>
        // Get all the audio elements
        var audioElements = document.querySelectorAll('audio');

        // Loop through the audio elements and add event listeners
        audioElements.forEach(function(audio) {
            audio.addEventListener('play', function() {
                // Pause all other audio elements
                audioElements.forEach(function(element) {
                    if (element !== audio) {
                        element.pause();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you seen the source code of the html page? is there <source src="data:audio/mp3;base64...">' base64 code?

Comment: @DarkShade Yes the player with the src="data:audio/mp3;base64...">' base64 code is echoed in the PHP

Comment: can You one page source code (with base64 codes) to some online etitors or git

Comment: It works for me. How large is the audio data? If it's not too much large, can you share one encoded string?

Comment: @shingo  About 25.1 KiB